# Laravel eager loading model same name constraint

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

i've got a Goal model which got a attribute named stopover.
Furthermore this model has a hasMany-Relationship to a model called Stopover.
When i'm trying to get a goal via

```
$goal = Goal::find(1)->with("stopover")
```

then i'm running into problems because of the two identically named values. If im using

```
$goal->stopover
```

it's returning the attributes value, thats fine. 
BUT! how can i get the related model Stopover now? I hope you see the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use the same name, but here's how you can get it: `$goal->getRelation('stopover')`. However it will not work as dynamic property, so you need to load that relation first (like you did using `with` or using lazy loading: `$goal->load('stopover')`)

Comment: Thank you for that! i'll rename the attribute and go for it ;)